# Missing "Profile AS" - "Java Application" in eclipse (mars)

Tags: java, eclipse, profiler, eclipse-mars

I have a standalone Java application developed in eclipse (mars). I can run the application by right clicking the Main class and selecting "Run As" - "Java application". Debugging is also possible with "Debug As" - "Java Application".

Now I want to profile the Java application in eclipse. But if I do a right click on my Main class and select "Profile As" the sub menu "Java Application" is missing. Only the sub menus "Profile on Server..." and "Profile configurations..." are available. Also under "Profile configurations..." I can only add/set Server configurations, but not for a standalone Java application.

Are there any eclipse or JDK Settings missing for profiling a Java application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Profile As' was provided by the Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform Project

http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/

This project has been discontinued though so you can't do it any more unless you go back and get Europa or Castillo

You can use JConsole or JVisualVM to do similar sorts of things.